# Creating a bot-like configuration with ejabberd?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

How to implement a bot with ejabberd?

The idea is that on my (Debian 7.0 Wheezy) VPS, I'm running ejabberd and there I have a special bot Jabber user with limited set of commands that he can run.  Let's call him butler@myvps.foo.

On another box (say, my android phone), I have a Jabber client connected to my account at possibly a third party server.  Let's call it me@somewhere.bar.

Now I want ejabberd to:

- allow only one specific Jabber ID, me@somewhere.bar to ever communicate with this
  butler@myvps.foo.
- have everything typed into chat with butler@myvps.foo passed to shell and executed
  as a command, possibly in a chrooted or another protected environment (e.g. using
  a specific limited user).  (And the STDOUT + STDERR returned as a reply, of course.)

I understand there can be security risks, but for now I just want to know if this the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write a bot in any language and have it connect to the XMPP server as a client. A list of [XMPP client libraries can be found here](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/).

The bot can check the JID in the 'from' attribute of messages it receives to verify identity. It is not generally possible to forge a JID in XMPP, as servers authenticate their clients and also each other. In reality however it is only as secure as the authentication methods used (and the server containing no bugs).

To execute commands and read the results, a PTY is a good easy solution. There are PTY libraries available in many languages, including [Python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pty.html), [Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html) and [Lua](http://www.tset.de/lpty/).

You are right that security is an issue, as with any system. Years of effort have gone into securing ssh, and issues still arise occasionally.

It is worth noting that Google's XMPP server does not support encryption for server-to-server connections, so someone on a network between your XMPP server and Google's would be able to see your messages, and potentially modify and/or forge them completely.

And finally, even if they did support encryption for the server-to-server link... Google themselves technically have the ability to send messages as you, and your phone would also be a potential weak point.

Isolating the target process will remove a lot of security concerns. If the server runs on Linux, [LXC containers](http://lxc.sourceforge.net/) might be a good solution for you.

Hopefully this covers all aspects of your question!